# Full width centered submenu inside a Bootstrap .container menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to make a submenu like [these guys](https://dialpad.com/voice-and-video) have, but with Bootstrap 4. And I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

My navigation needs to be inside a .container and then my submenu needs to be full width with links centered in the middle. Which means if I want to do the appear on hover action with CSS, I'd have to place the submenu inside the main nav, right? And then have its position as absolute and width 100%. That's how I'd figured I should do it. But firstly, it doesn't seem to work like that at all (it won't stretch to full width). And if I add width: 100vw, then I can't make it responsive and centered.

Can someone please help me with this one? Or offer me a jQuery solution? Because I've been trying that, too, but my submenu keeps vanishing when my mouse leaves the .solution-link and I try to hover over submenu items.

Here's my code so far:

```css
.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.submenu .nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.solutions-link:hover .submenu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="menu-wrap">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-toggleable">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleContainer" aria-controls="navbarsExampleContainer" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleContainer">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item solutions-link">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Solutions</a>

            <div class="submenu">
              <ul class="nav justify-content-center navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- /.nav -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.submenu -->
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<!-- /.menu-wrap -->
```

**EDIT**: Forgot to include my jQuery code. For this, I've placed my submenu outside the main nav, but haven't managed to fix one thing. It still vanishes when the mouse leaves the .solutions-link to go to the submenu items. Is there a way I could fix that, while keeping the submenu outside the main nav?

```
var sub_menu_timer;
  $('.solutions-link').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      $('.submenu').show();
                },
    mouseleave: function () {
      $('.submenu').hide();
                }
});
```

Comment: add this property to .submenu .nav{left:0} and give a try..

Comment: @ChandraShekhar I've tried that. Adding the left:0; right:0 too. But it still ends up looking like this http://pokit.org/get/img/943b097eb2038f10869f14e06a091e92.jpg And I need it full width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards for setting your `submenu` width to `100%`, You might need to set its `position` to be `fixed` and set `left` to `0` as mentioned:

```
.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.submenu .nav {
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
}
.solutions-link:hover .submenu {
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle to see the expected results:
https://jsfiddle.net/99rzyt03/

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: That's it! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a bunch, eeya! +1

Comment: Glad we could help =)

Comment: @eeya , but what if i add some lorem after .menu-wrap div and scroll the page down???

Comment: Can you elaborate further?

Comment: This solution only works if the entire menu is fixed, otherwise content scrolling will scroll the header away, but not the submenu.